# solution of 2d laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

$G(x,\zeta)=\ln\left(x^2 + \zeta^2 \right)$ is a solution of the equation $\left(\partial_\zeta^2 + \partial_x^2 \right) G(x,\zeta) = 0$ if $x,\zeta>0$.
Now I thought if I transform $\zeta=Rz$ and $x=\frac{R^2}{2}$ then $\left( \frac{1}{R} \partial_z^2 + \partial_R \frac{1}{R} \partial_R \right) G\left(\frac{R^2}{2},Rz\right)$ would be a solution too, but it is not zero. Why is that? Is it not possible to transform $\zeta=Rz$ in the sense that R is an independent (constant) variable or do I always need to consider the combined transformation, that is the total differential of $\zeta$ ?
I would have thought I can transform twice independently of each other.

Comment: $R$ is given in terms of $x$ so it's **not** constant

Comment: Yes but z is independent of x so can I not define $\partial_\zeta = \frac{1}{R} \partial_z$ ?

Comment: I mean: Starting with \begin{align} \left( \frac{1}{R} \partial_z^2 + \partial_R \frac{1}{R} \partial_R \right) G = 0 \end{align} dividing by R and defining $\partial_R x = R$ yields \begin{align}\left( \frac{1}{R} \partial_z \frac{1}{R} \partial_z + \partial_x^2 \right) G = 0\end{align} and now I thought I could do the same with $\zeta$.

Comment: I think the issue is as mentioned in the opening question, that I always need to consider the combined transformation i.e. $\zeta=R(x)z$ and $X=x$ in this case and this means I cannot leave the x-Term as it is.

Answer (score 1):

By the multivariable chainrule

\begin{align}
\partial_R &= \partial_x x_R + \partial_\zeta \zeta_R = R\partial_x + z\partial_\zeta \\
\partial_z &= \partial_x x_z + \partial_\zeta \zeta_z = R\partial_\zeta
\end{align}

Solving the system of equations gives

\begin{align}
\partial_x &= \frac{1}{R^2}(R\partial_R - z\partial_z) \\
\partial_\zeta &= \frac{1}{R}\partial_z
\end{align}

The issue is likely with your $\partial_x$ derivation. Your Laplacian can't be right since it would also have to include $\partial_{Rz}$.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if given an operator like above, there exists a transformation such that the resulting Operator (including a possible redefinition of $G=g\cdot \tilde{G}$) is diagonal in the derivatives, or at least every derivative has constant coefficients?